# How do you find the probability of a continuous-time markov chain, where having started in state $i$, will be in $j$ state at time $t$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process

This is the three-state continuous-time Markov chain in which the transition rates are given by:

$$Q =  \left[ \begin{matrix}
    0 & 2\lambda & 0 \\
    \lambda & 0 & \lambda \\
    0 & 2\lambda & 0 \\
    \end{matrix}
\right]
$$

I need to find the probability that of the state starting $i$, will be in $j$ state at time $t$?I am suppose to use differential equations but I am not sure how to. The hint given is:

***Hint: Whenever confronted with an ordinary differential equation of the form x′(t) = ax(t)+b(t), it might be beneficial to consider the function y(t) = $e^{−at}x(t)$.***

Comment: Shouldn't the rows of the generator matrix each add to $0$?

Comment: @jeremy909 The generator matrix would be $$G =  \left[ \begin{matrix}
    -2\lambda & 2\lambda & 0 \\
    \lambda & -2\lambda & \lambda \\
    0 & 2\lambda & -2\lambda \\
    \end{matrix}
\right]
$$

I am suppose to use the symmetry to solve the ODE. I think the symmetry is that the probability of starting in state 2 going to state 1 =  to the probability of starting in state 2 and going to state 3. Similarly, the probability of starting in state 1 going to state 2 =  to the probability of starting in state 3 and going to state 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The generator matrix is
$$
G =  \left[ \begin{matrix}     -2\lambda & 2\lambda & 0 \\     \lambda & -2\lambda & \lambda \\     0 & 2\lambda & -2\lambda \\     \end{matrix} \right].
$$
Now, if $P(t) = \mathbb P(X(t)=j\mid X(0)=i)$, then $P$ satisfies the backward Kolmogorov equation
$$
P'(t) = GP(t),
$$
which has unique solution $e^{tG}$. Now, $G$ has eigenvalues $-4\lambda, -2\lambda, 0$ with corresponding eigenvectors $(1, -1, 1), (-1, 0, 1), (1, 1, 1)$. It follows that
$$
G = ADA^{-1}
$$
where
$$
A = \left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 1 & -1 & 1 \\
 -1 & 0 & 1 \\
 1 & 1 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right),\quad
D  =\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 -4 \lambda  & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & -2 \lambda  & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right).
$$
For each nonnegative integer $n$ we have $G^n = AD^nA^{-1}$, and hence
$$
e^{tG} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(tG)^n}{n!} = \left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 \frac{1}{4} e^{-4 \lambda  t} \left(e^{2 \lambda  t}+1\right)^2 & \frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2} e^{-4 \lambda  t} & e^{-2 \lambda  t} \sinh ^2(\lambda  t) \\
 \frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{4} e^{-4 \lambda  t} & \frac{1}{2} \left(e^{-4 \lambda  t}+1\right) & \frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{4} e^{-4 \lambda  t} \\
 e^{-2 \lambda  t} \sinh ^2(\lambda  t) & \frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2} e^{-4 \lambda  t} & \frac{1}{4} e^{-4 \lambda  t} \left(e^{2 \lambda  t}+1\right)^2 \\
\end{array}
\right).
$$